# Vuetify use 2 IconFonts

Tags: icons, vuetify.js, icon-fonts

Currently I'm using google fonts icons in my project, but I want to use also FAS5 Icons

I'm using this vuetify configuration, but the [documentation](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons/) doesn't say anithing about this.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';
import colors from "vuetify/lib/util/colors";
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
    theme: {
        ...
    },
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'fa'
    }
});
```

This is a clumsy example of what I'm doing. But I'm afraid this is bad practice and may create bugs or errors

```html
<v-btn icon @click="$vuetify.theme.dark = !$vuetify.theme.dark">
    <v-icon>nightlight_round</v-icon>
</v-btn>

<v-btn icon @click="$vuetify.theme.dark = !$vuetify.theme.dark">
    <v-icon>fa-moon</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [vuetify issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11224):

> You need to install all fonts you need or add links to CDNs, iconfont only specifies which icon set will be used for default Vueitfy icons

So there is no way to load multiple fonts on initialization.

I would keep the mostly used font as default in the Vuetify config and load the other one as needed. In the [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#font-awesome-5-icons) the same implementation of FA5 as yours is shown, so I would say you've done it correctly.